# Criando project templates no vs com projetos existentes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, create-project

Estou tentando criar um `project template` no vs 2017 usando o `SideWaffle`, o problema é que ele referencia projetos existentes em pastas separadas. ex:

sln: projeto A
     bibliotecas\ projeto b
     bibliotecas\ projeto c

o projeto b e projeto c estão em pastas anteriores e estes devem ser compartilhados e referenciados no projeto A, o template deve criar a sln dessa forma, atualmente ou ele cria o projeto A sem os outros projetos mas com a referencia ou ele recria os outros projetos duplicando o código inteiro a cada projeto.

Alguem sabe de alguma forma de criar esse template?

Comment: Se os outros projetos são bibliotecas e você não quer que os projetos sejam incluídos na sua solution, eles devem ser incluídos apenas como referência. O ideal seria você ter um repositório nuget para disponibilizar seus binários e incluir no seu projeto A apenas as dependências dos packages.

Comment: Na verdade é o oposto, eu quero que eles ja venham incluídos, sem serem recriados, eles são projetos em outras pastas (nunca mudam), precisava criar o template com eles ja incluidos

Comment: E como você fará versionamento? Está usando o TFS, GIT ou SVN?

Comment: uso o TFS para versionamento